# C# MVC Send an email attachment of a print screen image

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, email-attachments, printscreen

This is for printing screen,

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

        printscreen.Save(@"filepath", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I tried putting this in my controller but it does not recognize Screen as anything.

This is for attaching,

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("you attachment file");
            mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Can I just add the filepath like this?: new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("filepath");

Comment: Is this ASP.NET?  Do you understand the difference between server side and client side code?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Windows code and can run on WinForm not on client browser.